# Passing Strings to a Class Method that passes information to stored SQL procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server

I've been struggling with an issue for a couple of days can't seem to work out why this code isn't doing what it's supposed to:

1. Signin Form upon pressing the submit button should take the text from the text boxes and send them to a method in a class called 'database connection'.
2. The 'Database connection' class has a method called Insert_Data, this should take those string values and then pass this information through to a stored proceedure in a local SQL database
3. the stored proceedure should execute with this information and populate a 'visitors' table.

Form SignIn:

Variables:

```
//DatabaseConnection databaseClass;
string strCon;
DatabaseConnection databaseClass;
```

Submit Button_Click Event:

```
        private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtFirstName.Text.Trim().Length > 0 && txtSurname.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            lblAsterisk.Visible = false;
            lblAsterisk2.Visible = false;
            lblComplete2.Visible = false;
            lblComplete1.Visible = false;

            databaseClass = new DatabaseConnection();
            databaseClass.Insert_Data(txtFirstName.Text.Trim(), txtSurname.Text.Trim(), txtVisiting.Text.Trim(), txtReg.Text.Trim());

            MessageBox.Show("submitted information");
```

DatabaseConnection Class that the method is calling:

```
class DatabaseConnection

    private string strCon;

    public string connection_String
    {
        set { strCon = value; }
    }

    public void Insert_Data(string datFirstname, string datSurname, string datVisiting, string datReg)
    {

        strCon = Properties.Settings.Default.VistiorsConnectionString;
        SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(strCon);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Submit_Data", connect);

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Connection.Open();

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Firstname", datFirstname));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Surname", datSurname));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Visiting", datVisiting));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Car_Reg", datReg));

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
```

Stored Procedure (Submit_Data):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Submit_Data

@Firstname varChar(50),
@Surname varChar(50),
@Visiting varChar(50),
@Car_Reg nchar(10)

AS
Insert into tbl_visitors(Firstname, Surname, Visiting, Car_Reg)
values (@Firstname, @Surname, @Visiting, @Car_Reg)

RETURN 0
```

Those are the three stages to what I'm trying to do. I know that it physically calls the DatabaseConnection class, and I know that if i manually execute the stored proceedure that it works, but I can't seem to pass through the data to the stored proceedure. Any help is appreciated.

Just to clarify, when the program is executed there are no errors thrown up, everything appears to load, the main issue is that once the submit button is pressed, no new data is being added to the database.

Comment: What happens? Error? Incorrect data?

Comment: You have to **use** your parameters in your SQL statement

Comment: OK - you haven't told us what is actually happening when you run this.  Do you get an error?  Is there anything in the DB?

Comment: Check the return value of cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Would also note that aside from anything else, you are not closing or disposing of your DB connection.

Comment: Add a close to Connection too  cmd.Connection.Close();

Comment: Hello sorry, theres no error when the program is ran; the code all seems to execute correctly. The issue is that when I check the database no new entries are being added.

Comment: can you manually go to db and execute the query and see if anything happens?

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the same database that you are executing your insert on?

Comment: I can manually execute the query from the Database and it seems to work without any issues, there just seems to be some reason why its not passing the information from the class to the stored procedure... During debugging I can see that the string values from the method are being sent to the class correctly though.

Comment: @Paddy & @ NDJ , yes definately the same database, which is why I'm at a bit of a loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do see is that you do not close the connection after you execute the query. The problem might be there.

I will recommend you another approach, exemplified by this portion of code:

```
using (var command = new SqlCommand("Submit_Data", connect) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure }) 
{
   connect.Open();

   command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Firstname", datFirstname));
   command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Surname", datSurname));
   command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Visiting", datVisiting));
   command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Car_Reg", datReg));

   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   connect.Close();
}
```

I hope this solution helps you and answers your question.

Comment: This along with a change of the commands solved the problem, changed the syntax to cmd.Paramaters.AddWithValue()  and it apears to work, bit of a strange one.

Comment: It definitely is strange if the `command.Parameters.Add` method does not work properly.